# CSV Download from PHP space issue

Tags: php, csv, download

Whenever there is a CSV file with `space` in name like `xyz abc.csv` we are facing an issue to download via PHP Code, while other CSV like which has no space within, works fine and downloads properly.

Below is my download code:

```
$file_path = 'http://www.servername.com/subfolder/subfolder/';
$file = urlencode('Today new_18-10-2012_21-13-21.csv');

header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file.'"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');
readfile($file_path.$file);
```

When file gets download, its always `0 bytes` while the original file is `93kb` in size

Any suggestions for this trouble.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this... You have to use `rawurlencode` instead of `urlencode`.

```
$file_path = 'http://www.servername.com/subfolder/subfolder/';

//just filename, no need to save file with url encoded name!
$file = 'Today new_18-10-2012_21-13-21.csv';

header('Content-Type: application/csv');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $file . '"');
header('Pragma: no-cache');

//here comes url encoding
readfile($file_path . rawurlencode($file));
```

*Its working fine for me...*

Answer (score 0):

Use this code. It may helpful to you. But i thing the main issue is spacing.

```
$Filename = 'Today new_18-10-2012_21-13-21.csv'; 
$path = "http://www.servername.com/subfolder/subfolder/";
$file = $path.$filename;
header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename");
header("Content-Type: application/csv");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
readfile($file);
```

Comment: what is supposed to do the function savedata1? The content type is wrong. What improves your code?

Comment: there is no need of savedata1. It is a function which saved your data in database.